# "No route matches [PATCH] "/authors/posts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I tap the update button after doing an edit to a post, I get

From the Chrome Browser

`"No route matches [PATCH] "/authors/posts"`

From the Command line

> "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/authors/posts"):"

Here is the Routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :authors
  root to: 'blog/posts#index'
  # /author/posts
  namespace :authors do
    resources :posts
  end

  scope module: 'blog' do
    get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
    get 'posts' => 'posts#index', as: :posts
    get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :post
  end
  end
```

Here is the edit.html.erb file:

```
<% provide(:page_title, "Edit #{@post.title}") %>
<% provide(:author, 'active') %>
<h1>Editing Post</h1>

<%= render 'form', post: @post, url: authors_post_url(@post) %>



<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', authors_post_path %>
```

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and show the result?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `posts` model is nested inside `authors` model so shouldn't your routes should be like

```
resources :authors do
  resources: posts
end
```

Comment: Someone else told me that I'm not passing the postID...still working on solving this but thanks for your input.